How to anchor VWAP to pivot highs/lows
I am trying to anchor VWAP to pivot Highs and Lows using functions ta.pivothigh & ta.pivotlow with ta.vwap. The trouble is when ta.pivothigh/low is used as the anchor argument in the ta.vwap function, the vwap is delayed by the rightbars argument of ta.pivothigh/low function. In other words, VWAP is anchored on the bar the pivot condition is confirmed by a rightbars lookahead. Is there a workaround so the anchored VWAP actually starts at pivots? Here is the code:
//@version=5
indicator("Automated Anchored VWAP", shorttitle="aaVWAP", overlay=true)
vw_g1   = "Pivots Settings"
vw_g2   = "Tracking Settings"
s_piv   = input(true,       "Show Pivots",          group=vw_g1)
_lb     = input.int(10,     "Left Bars Lookback",   group=vw_g1)
_rb     = input.int(10,     "Right Bars Lookahead", group=vw_g1)

c_ph    = ta.pivothigh(_lb, _rb)
c_pl    = ta.pivotlow(_lb, _rb)
_lh     = ta.valuewhen(c_ph, c_ph, 0) < ta.valuewhen(c_ph[1], c_ph[1], 0)
_hh     = ta.valuewhen(c_ph, c_ph, 0) > ta.valuewhen(c_ph[1], c_ph[1], 0)
_ll     = ta.valuewhen(c_pl[1], c_pl[1], 0) > ta.valuewhen(c_pl, c_pl, 0)
_hl     = ta.valuewhen(c_pl[1], c_pl[1], 0) < ta.valuewhen(c_pl, c_pl, 0)



// Pivot Plotshapes
plotshape(s_piv ? _hh : na, 'Higher High', style=shape.square, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.green, 50), text='[HH]', offset=-_rb, size=size.auto)
plotshape(s_piv ? _lh : na, 'Higher Low',  style=shape.square, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.red, 50),   text='[LH]', offset=-_rb, size=size.auto)
plotshape(s_piv ? _ll : na, 'Lower Low',   style=shape.square, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.red, 50),   text='[LL]', offset=-_rb, size=size.auto)
plotshape(s_piv ? _hl : na, 'Lower High',  style=shape.square, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.green, 50), text='[HL]', offset=-_rb, size=size.auto)

[vwap, upper, lower] = ta.vwap(open, c_ph, 1)
plot(vwap)
plot(upper, color = color.green)
plot(lower, color = color.green)


one of my indicators does this, it's open source. You can copy the method vwapper https://www.tradingview.com/script/yGQMVJ90-Auto-Anchored-Swing-VWAP-s/

Thanks for your reply, I have checked out your indicator before, however, your indicator plots only the latest vwaps, but I need all vwaps for strategy backtesting. I would also like standard deviations, which the original code "Automated Anchored VWAP" from kurtsmock doesn't have.  I am trying to get a hierarchy of VWAPs similar to "Nubia - Auto Midas Anchored VWAP" by xdecow, but that code does not anchor properly to swing points as it can drop off swing points after length parameters are elapsed.

you can keep past vwaps by not clearing the arrays in my script. similar calculate the standard deviation and plot it using a polyline

Thanks for the pointers. Unfortunately, my knowledge of arrays is in disarray.
